# Django restframework-simple-jwt: PEM formatted key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to use django-simplejwt & restframework with RSA256. I generated my keypair by following [this](https://gist.github.com/ygotthilf/baa58da5c3dd1f69fae9) gist. The public & private keypair are being saved in a .env file:

```
JWT_SIGNING_KEY='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\n
                             keydata\\n
                 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

JWT_VERIFYING_KEY='-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\\n
                             keydata\\n
                   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

My jwt configuration settings.py looks like this (additional info is for compatibility with Auth0):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}

SIGNING_KEY = os.getenv("JWT_SIGNING_KEY")
VERIFYING_KEY = os.getenv("JWT_VERIFYING_KEY")
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'user_id',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timezone.timedelta(minutes=10),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timezone.timedelta(hours=6),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM' : 'RS256',  # Default would be HS256
    'SIGNING_KEY' : f'''{SIGNING_KEY}''',  #config("JWT_SIGNING_KEY"),  # Must be private key
    'VERIFYING_KEY' : f'''{VERIFYING_KEY}''',  #config("JWT_VERIFYING_KEY"),  # Must be public key
    'AUDIENCE' : config("JWT_AUDIENCE"),
    'ISSUER': config("JWT_ISSUER"),
    'JWK_URL': f'{config("JWT_ISSUER")}/.well-known/jwks.json',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': f'{config("JWT_AUDIENCE")}/email',
    'JTI_CLAIM': None,
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
}
```

When restricted views that need a user object are being called, a function for decoding the jwt token and returning the corresponding user object is being executed:

```
def token_user(request):
    s, token = request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].split(" ")
    decoded = jwt.decode(token, settings.VERIFYING_KEY, algorithms=["RSA256"])
    username = decoded["username"]

    user = get_user_model().objects.filter(username=username)

    return user
```

Here are my Login view & LoginSerializer (I cut out most of the validation process since this worked before implementing jwt. I left the part generating the token):

```
#views.py
class Login(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

#serializers.py
class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    username_field = get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
    
        token['username'] = user.username

        return token

    def validate(self, attrs):
        ....
        refresh = self.get_token(user)
        attrs["refresh"] = str(refresh)
        attrs["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)
        ....
```

When trying out the Login I get the following Error:

> TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key.